# Problema con resolucion de dominio www. DNS window server 2016

Tags: servidor, dns, windows-server

Buen dia

Que tal, he tenido un problema particular en mi red, he notado que mi dominio www.prueba.com, que esta en un
hosting externo al abrirlo en el explorador, abre sin problemas mientras lo ponga asi, pero si por ejemplo dígito

prueba.com me aparece un error que dice 404 no foud.

El proveedor de hosting dice que pueden ser mis DNS, en mi caso tengo un servidor en DNS en un window server 2016,
la pregunta es, que podría hacer o revisar en mi servidor de DNS, para evitar este comportamiento del dominio.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La petición está llegando a algún servidor porque sino en el navegador no te aparecería un error 404 sino algo como "No se puede acceder al sitio web".

Podría ser que la petición no llegue al servidor donde tienes el hosting y llegue a otro servidor (poco probable), para ello comprueba en tu servidor DNS que tienes dos registros www.prueba.com y prueba.com y que ambos apuntan a la misma dirección IP (la de tu hosting, que según explicas debería ser la que hay en el registro de www.prueba.com).

Si lo anterior está correcto, lo más probable es que se trate de un problema de configuración del servidor web en el hosting. Tienes (tú o tu proveedor) que configurarlo para que sirva contenido escuchando www.prueba.com y prueba.com (idealmente lo haría con una redirección permanente de uno a otro).

Es difícil ayudarte más sin conocer detalles del hosting y servidor web.

Comment: Gracias compañeros, agradezco su valiosa información, voy a revisar, tan pronto exista solución la publicare acá.

Answer (score 0):

En particular para `www` suele ser al contrario:
`prueba.com` debe ser el dominio y `www` es un *alias* (CNAME).

Comment: He actualizado en mi pregunta una imagen, en esta la que tengo problema es risaralda.gov.co, pero no se en donde verificar lo del dominio con www. sin www.